# Adding a bit of server-side dynamic client javascript to a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify

I'm looking into the [Shopify Embedded App SDK](https://docs.shopify.com/embedded-app-sdk/initialization) and theres a part where you have to drop a bit of javascript from server-side variables. I'm using [react engine](https://github.com/paypal/react-engine), [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) and [express.js](http://expressjs.com/).

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/external/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ShopifyApp.init({
      apiKey: 'YOUR_APP_API_KEY',
      shopOrigin: 'https://CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_SHOP.myshopify.com'
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

There is a way to provide `red.render(req.url, data)` data, however I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with it from within a component. Is there a way to access and change the global `ShopifyApp` variable from within a component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the shopify code to the `componentDidMount` of the `App` component (top most component in react-routes).

```
var Layout = require('./layout.jsx');
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');

module.exports = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function(){
    if(this.props.shopify){
      ShopifyApp.init({
        apiKey: this.props.shopify.apiKey,
        shopOrigin: this.props.shopify.shopOrigin
      })
    }
  },
  render: function render() {
    return (
      <Layout {...this.props}>
        <Router.RouteHandler {...this.props}/>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
});
```